# Errors when moving a specific commit to a new branch with Git

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

I have this:

```
branch-1     a--b--c--d
```

I need this:

```
branch-1     a--c--d
branch-2     b
```

I tried this:

```
$git checkout -b branch-2
$git cherry-pick <SHA-1 b>
```

But I got this:

```
error: could not apply <SHA-1 b>... [comment]
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

So I did `$git status` and got `Unmerged paths ... both modified: .gitignore`. I `git add`ed and `git commit`ted before trying again, only to get the same error msg again.

How do I move a particular commit onto a new branch?

Comment: `branch-1` and `branch-2` don't have any common ancestor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you commited the merge, that completed the cherry-pick on `branch-2`. You shouldn't run `cherry-pick` again. Cherry-pick won't change the history of `branch-1` so you'll need to use interactive rebase to do that.